# I'm getting 401 Invalid Token, Invalid Value but only sometimes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I've the following Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String r = null;

    try {

        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory( DATA_STORE_DIR );

        Credential credential = authorize();

        String accesToken = credential.getAccessToken();

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        WebTarget googleTarget = client.target( "https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/foo-project-name/zones/europe-west6-a/instances" );

        // Accesstoken getting from playground would be working!!!

        r = googleTarget.request( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE ).header( "Authorization", "Bearer " + accesToken ).get( String.class );


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println( r );
}
```

The Part here is coming from: https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/compute-engine-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/computeengine/cmdline/ComputeEngineSample.java

```
    /**
     * Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data.
     */
    private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        // initialize client secrets object
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets;
        // load client secrets
        clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load( JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(
                RestForecast.class.getResourceAsStream( "/client_secrets.json" ) ) );
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith( "Enter" )
                || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith( "Enter " )) {
            System.out.println( "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/ "
                    + "into compute-engine-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json" );
            System.exit( 1 );
        }
        // set up authorization code flow
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES ).setDataStoreFactory( dataStoreFactory )
                .build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp( flow, new LocalServerReceiver() ).authorize( "user" );
    }
```

When I'm using the AccessToken which I can get from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground, then the request is always working (at least i didn't see it not working).

When I'm using the AccessToken from the Credential Library, then sometimes it works, and sometimes I'm getting the following Error:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:160)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:135)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:425)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.get(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:165)
    at RestForecast.main(RestForecast.java:77)
```

any idea?

The Detailed Message from the 401 is: **Invalid Token**, **Invalid Value**

Comment: Where is this code coming from? `Credential credential = authorize();
`

Comment: There are piece of dead code. Can you clean it to have a better view on the issue?

Comment: @JohnHanley, I did put the Function in, and the Link from where is coming from.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I don't see there any Dead Code... can you tell me which one you mean?

Comment: @fbz, now, in authorize, you use your httpTransport

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks! your hint did help me to find the working solution:
replaced to code above with:

```
Compute.Instances.List requestHttp = computeService.instances().list( "projectName", "europe-west6-a" );

InstanceList insList = requestHttp.execute();

private static Compute createComputeService(HttpTransport httpTransport, Credential credential) {
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        return new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential ).setApplicationName( "Google-ComputeSample/0.1" ).build();
    }
```